# Ignore errors and mismatch types while inserting row to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image: MYSQL TABLE]

I have a MySQL database as above, with all Null set to Yes except UID. The data will be collected from a survey and it works when all the entries fit the "Type" defined by MySQL.

Here's a problem though, sometimes users may input something that doesn't fit the criteria, for e.g.: "a user input varchar(4) in **age** instead of int(3)".

What happens now, is the whole row will not be inserted as a result of that single error. What I want to do is to have a way, so that only **age**'s entry will be omitted. I thought setting Null to Yes can solve the problem but apparently it can't. Please help :)

Comment: In your survey data collection code, can you check that age will fit in int(3)?

Comment: You can always insert an int(4) into and int(3). They are both integers. See mysql's documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/numeric-types.html I also don't think that you can do this with MySQL. You should check the user's data before trying to insert it.

Comment: however if someone insert varchar(4) instead of int(3)?

Comment: You can always... I don't know... validate the input to make sure it fits? And maybe umm... throw an error to the user if it doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

`ALLOW NULL` doesn't mean "if invalid, insert NULL". You should validate the data prior to the insert.

You can use the [IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) key word when inserting like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl
```

Which provides the following functionality:

> Data conversions that would trigger errors abort the statement if
>   IGNORE is not specified. With IGNORE, invalid values are adjusted to
>   the closest values and inserted; warnings are produced but the
>   statement does not abort. You can determine with the mysql_info() C
>   API function how many rows were actually inserted into the table.

So data conversion errors will not abort, but constraint errors will abort like a duplicate unique or primary key.

Comment: Good answer! And it also indicates that I was confused about how IGNORE works. However, the syntax is `INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl` and not `INSERT INTO tbl IGNORE`.

Comment: Also, when I tested SQL's "convert to the closest value" feature, it looks like it casts strings inserted in an int field to 0, which could be a problem if any of the fields can have 0 as a valid entry (e.g., if one of the questions is "how many cats do you have," you can't tell the difference between someone who typed "0" and someone who typed "way too many to count").  Do you know if there's any way to change this behavior?

Comment: @octern, oops. thanks. I fixed the order of the IGNORE. I don't see any workaround for the varchar conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you should be validating the data yourself to make sure it's the right type, and possibly giving the user an error message if they enter something invalid. Use the simple function [`is_numeric($age)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to find out if age is a valid number. If it is, you can go on to use `$age = intval($age)` to prevent some smartypants from entering their age as 18.1667. If $age isn't a number, you can manually set it to null and it will be entered into your database that way.

A slightly faster way would be to just include the code `(int)$age` as part of your insert query. However, casting a string to an int gives 0, and for some fields 0 may also be a valid response! So don't do that.